# not generate Release build while proguard enable

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I am trying to generate Release apk while proguard enable.

I am trying lots of thing i tried by add below line to proguard-rule.pro file

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-dontwarn com.mixpanel.**
-dontwarn org.acra.**
```

in this case my release build is generated but my application crash

if i am not add any line in proguard then 
I am getting error

```
Warning:com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.GCMReceiver: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
Warning:com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.Tweaks: can't find referenced class com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.Tweaks$TweakType
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:org.acra.ErrorReporter: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced method 'boolean isDefault()' in library class java.lang.reflect.Method
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

      Maybe this is library field 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger { java.lang.String name; }'
Note: org.acra.collector.DisplayManagerCollector accesses a field 'DISPLAY_SERVICE' dynamically
      Maybe this is library field 'android.content.Context { java.lang.String DISPLAY_SERVICE; }'
Note: org.acra.collector.DisplayManagerCollector accesses a field 'densityDpi' dynamically
      Maybe this is library field 'android.content.res.Configuration { int densityDpi; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.util.DisplayMetrics { int densityDpi; }'
Note: org.acra.collector.MediaCodecListCollector accesses a field 'colorFormats' dynamically
      Maybe this is library field 'android.media.MediaCodecInfo$CodecCapabilities { int[] colorFormats; }'
Note: org.acra.collector.MediaCodecListCollector accesses a field 'profileLevels' dynamically
      Maybe this is library field 'android.media.MediaCodecInfo$CodecCapabilities { android.media.MediaCodecInfo$CodecProfileLevel[] profileLevels; }'
Note: org.acra.collector.MediaCodecListCollector accesses a field 'profile' dynamically
      Maybe this is library field 'android.media.MediaCodecInfo$CodecProfileLevel { int profile; }'
Note: org.acra.collector.MediaCodecListCollector accesses a field 'level' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaf$zza { int level; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor { okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor$Level level; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.media.MediaCodecInfo$CodecProfileLevel { int level; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.net.wifi.ScanResult { int level; }'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.NavigationView { void setNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout { void setOnLayoutChangeListener(android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout$OnLayoutChangeListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout$OnLayoutChangeListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout { void setOnAttachStateChangeListener(android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout$OnAttachStateChangeListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout$OnAttachStateChangeListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout { void setOnTabSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$OnTabSelectedListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$OnTabSelectedListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout { void setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout { void setTabsFromPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager { void setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager { void setOnAdapterChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$OnAdapterChangeListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$OnAdapterChangeListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager { void setOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$OnPageChangeListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$OnPageChangeListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout { void setDrawerListener(android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView { void setOnScrollChangeListener(android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView$OnScrollChangeListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView$OnScrollChangeListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout { void setPanelSlideListener(android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$PanelSlideListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$PanelSlideListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout { void setOnRefreshListener(android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$OnRefreshListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$OnRefreshListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView { void setItemInvoker(android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder$ItemInvoker); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder$ItemInvoker'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView { void setPopupCallback(android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView$PopupCallback); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView$PopupCallback'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer { void setTabContainer(android.support.v7.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout { void setActionBarVisibilityCallback(android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$ActionBarVisibilityCallback); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$ActionBarVisibilityCallback'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView { void setPresenter(android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView { void setOnMenuItemClickListener(android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$OnMenuItemClickListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$OnMenuItemClickListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ActivityChooserView { void setActivityChooserModel(android.support.v7.widget.ActivityChooserModel); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ActivityChooserModel'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ActivityChooserView { void setProvider(android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout { void setAttachListener(android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout$OnAttachListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout$OnAttachListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsFrameLayout { void setOnFitSystemWindowsListener(android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsViewGroup$OnFitSystemWindowsListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsViewGroup$OnFitSystemWindowsListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout { void setOnFitSystemWindowsListener(android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsViewGroup$OnFitSystemWindowsListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsViewGroup$OnFitSystemWindowsListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setAccessibilityDelegateCompat(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setRecyclerListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setRecycledViewPool(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecycledViewPool); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecycledViewPool'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setViewCacheExtension(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewCacheExtension); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewCacheExtension'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setChildDrawingOrderCallback(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ChildDrawingOrderCallback); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ChildDrawingOrderCallback'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setOnScrollListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$OnScrollListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$OnScrollListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setItemAnimator(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { void setOnQueryTextListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { void setOnCloseListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnCloseListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnCloseListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { void setOnSuggestionListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnSuggestionListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnSuggestionListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { void setSuggestionsAdapter(android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$SearchAutoComplete { void setSearchView(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar { void setOnMenuItemClickListener(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$OnMenuItemClickListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$OnMenuItemClickListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat { void setOnInflateListener(android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat$OnInflateListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat$OnInflateListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase { void setFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton { void setDefaultAudience(com.facebook.login.DefaultAudience); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.DefaultAudience'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton { void setLoginBehavior(com.facebook.login.LoginBehavior); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.LoginBehavior'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton { void setToolTipStyle(com.facebook.login.widget.ToolTipPopup$Style); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.widget.ToolTipPopup$Style'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton { void setToolTipMode(com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$ToolTipMode); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$ToolTipMode'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton { void setProperties(com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$LoginButtonProperties); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$LoginButtonProperties'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton { void setLoginManager(com.facebook.login.LoginManager); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.LoginManager'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView { void setOnErrorListener(com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView$OnErrorListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView$OnErrorListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.share.internal.LikeBoxCountView { void setCaretPosition(com.facebook.share.internal.LikeBoxCountView$LikeBoxCountViewCaretPosition); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.share.internal.LikeBoxCountView$LikeBoxCountViewCaretPosition'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView { void setLikeViewStyle(com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$Style); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$Style'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView { void setAuxiliaryViewPosition(com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$AuxiliaryViewPosition); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$AuxiliaryViewPosition'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView { void setHorizontalAlignment(com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$HorizontalAlignment); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$HorizontalAlignment'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView { void setOnErrorListener(com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$OnErrorListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$OnErrorListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView { void setFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton { void setOnPlusOneClickListener(com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton$OnPlusOneClickListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton$OnPlusOneClickListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId { com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId getInstance(com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.mixpanel.android.surveys.CardCarouselLayout { void setOnQuestionAnsweredListener(com.mixpanel.android.surveys.CardCarouselLayout$OnQuestionAnsweredListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.mixpanel.android.surveys.CardCarouselLayout$OnQuestionAnsweredListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageView { void setRecycler(com.soundcloud.android.crop.ImageViewTouchBase$Recycler); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.soundcloud.android.crop.ImageViewTouchBase$Recycler'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.soundcloud.android.crop.ImageViewTouchBase { void setRecycler(com.soundcloud.android.crop.ImageViewTouchBase$Recycler); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.soundcloud.android.crop.ImageViewTouchBase$Recycler'
Note: there were 3 references to unknown classes.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
Note: there were 32 classes trying to access generic signatures using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the signature attributes
      (using '-keepattributes Signature').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
Note: there were 3 classes trying to access enclosing classes using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the inner classes attributes
      (using '-keepattributes InnerClasses').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
Note: there were 59 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
      (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
Note: there were 17 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Note: there were 14 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
      (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)
Warning:there were 40 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning:there were 3 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Here is my build gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.electrovese.eduqueri"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    dexOptions{
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.pixplicity.easyprefs:library:1.8.1@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.5.8@aar'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
    compile project(':payUMoneysdk')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: are you sure that `proguard.pro` is located in same dir as your build.gradle?

Comment: Yes, proguard.pro in app directory

Answer (score 1):

Every popular library usually defines Proguard rules. Support libraries, Picasso, OkHttp, Retrofit all have their rules, just look for them on the Internet next time. `-dontwarn` only masks the problem, usually not solving it. This time I put them all together:

```
### Android Support
-dontwarn android.support.**

-dontwarn android.support.design.**
-keep public class android.app.Notification
-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.R$* { *; }

-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}

# Retrofit 2.X
## https://square.github.io/retrofit/ ##

-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}

# OkHtpp 3
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Annotation
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**

# Picasso
-keep class com.squareup.picasso.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.picasso.** *;
}
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.picasso.** *;
}
-dontnote com.squareup.picasso.Utils
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader

# Acra
# keep this class so that logging will show 'ACRA' and not a obfuscated name like 'a'.
# Note: if you are removing log messages elsewhere in this file then this isn't necessary
-keep class org.acra.ACRA {
    *;
}

# keep this around for some enums that ACRA needs
-keep class org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode {
    *;
}

-keepnames class org.acra.sender.HttpSender$** {
    *;
}

-keepnames enum org.acra.ReportField {
    *;
}

# keep this otherwise it is removed by ProGuard
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
{
    public void addCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public void putCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public void removeCustomData(java.lang.String);}

# keep this otherwise it is removed by ProGuard
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
{
    public void handleSilentException(java.lang.Throwable);
}
-dontwarn android.app.Notification
```

This won't probably fix all your problems. Be aware, that I have not taken into account `compile project(':payUMoneysdk')` as it is too much work to import. When you encounter the problem, copy paste it into Google and search first.

**EDIT:**

In order to keep names use

```
-keepparameternames
```

If that won't help, then add those rules too:

```
-keep class {your.package.name}.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class {your.package.name}.** { *; }
```

Comment: there is problem it changed all api's parameter , please help me

Comment: Edited the answer.